# Is a JavaScript array iterator itself iterable according to ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The following works on the JavaScript runtimes I've checked (Node.js and Firefox):

```
let xs = [0, 1, 2]
let it = xs[Symbol.iterator]()
for (let x of it) console.log(x)
```

This works because the `it` iterator is itself iterable, i.e. it has a `Symbol.iterator` property. One could presume this is because `Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator]` is implemented as a generator.

My question is, can I *rely* on `it` being iterable? That is, is it required by the spec?

I've looked ([this](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createarrayiterator) is the relevant part, I think) and I can't find anything that says that an array iterator should be iterable, or that it must be implemented with a generator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can! All standard iterators for core objects extend [`%IteratorPrototype%`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-%iteratorprototype%-object) which specifically defines:

#### 25.1.2.1 %IteratorPrototype% [ @@iterator ] ( )

> The following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Return the `this` value.
>
> The value of the `name` property of this function is `[Symbol.iterator]`.

So every builtin iterator will automatically return itself when used as an iterable, so using it in a `for...of` or any other iteration context is safe.